# How to add multiple markers on mobile Google Map and display the content when click?

Tags: google-maps, cordova

hello i am working on the phonegap apps which can display the location markers on google map.

It is supposed to have a detail box pop up when i click on the marker, but it does not function.

can anyone help me to correct the code?

many thanks

```
    var mobileDemo = { 'center': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'zoom': 8 };

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $('#basic_map').live('pageinit', function() {
            demo.add('basic_map', function() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': mobileDemo.center, 'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':true,
                 'callback': function() {
                    var self = this;
                    self.addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() }).click(function() {
                        self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': 'Hello World!' }, this);
                    });
                }});

                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { position: new google.maps.LatLng(57.9973333,12.0502107)})
                           .click(function() {

                            var self = this;
                              self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': 'Hello Worl23!' }, this);
                     } )

                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { position: new google.maps.LatLng(57.373333,12.0502107)})
                           .click(function() {

                            var self = this;
                              self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': 'Hello Worl234!' }, this);
                     } )

                }).load('basic_map');
        });

        $('#basic_map').live('pageshow', function() {
            demo.add('basic_map', function() { $('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh'); }).load('basic_map');
        });



    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a easier way to use Google Maps api,https://github.com/HPNeo/gmaps.   And what you need almost like this,http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples/markers.html,  you click the marker and the detail info shows

Comment: many thanks for ur solution. can u also tell me how to make it mobile friendly? (optimise the screen size or 100%width... rather than appearing a scroll bar.) =)

Comment: you have to learn about responsive web design,see at http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design ,and you can try twitter's bootstrap .